# wicket page having 2 forms, detect form modification behaviour

Tags: java, wicket

I am working in wicket framework for last 6 months.

How do i detect fields in the form are changed when navigating or closing page and show a dialog  box?

I am serializing the form `onload` and `onunload` but it's not working when I have 2 forms in a page.

How can i apply this behaviour to file components.

Thanks in advance,
Sagar.

Comment: Not sure if I get this right: Do you want to be able to detect this on client side, ie JavaScript? Like "you have unsaved changes, do you want to continue"?

Comment: OK, and what exactly is not working then? Why can't you simply add the respective jQuery calls? Remember, if a form has changed; if one has, give a meaningful message in the onUnload event. What exactly does this have to do with Wicket?

Comment: i am having "jquery.formSavior.js" file which will take care of handling form change but i have to pass form id to this library... how can i pass that id which is generating dynamically?

Plz look my Javascript code that i am adding in java


response.renderJavascript(
   "\n"
    + "jQuery(document).ready(function($) { \n"
    + "  $('#personInfo').formSavior( { \n"
    + " 'msg' : 'User information changes have not been saved.' } ); \n"
    + "\n" + "});\n", "formChange");

Comment: If a page is having form and i add/edit the elements of the form and navigate to other page without saving then it should ask for confirmation, how can i do it by using some JQuery library or any other suggesstions is accepted...?I have added a behaviour that's working fine if i have a single form but if a form has another form hidden in it then it's asking confirmation even if i open the hidden form.. that's my complete problem